# Is there a system within D6 that allows you to level up your Attributes?

Tags: d6-system

I know for a fact that there's a system within the game that allows you to increase skills by using character points based on the die score of the skills you're trying to raise, but is there a way to do the same with Attributes?

Comment: Is this a different system than Star Wars d6? B/c there attributes can be raised the same way skills can, only the cost is 10 times higher. (E.g. 2d+1 --> 2d+2 will cost you 20 points)

Comment: There are many versions of d6 but they all fall under a blanket system. Star wars d6 is one of the versions. There's also d6 fantasy, d6 space, d6 adventure, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I wrote an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not Usually, But Sometimes Yes

From d6 Fantasy, Improving Characters (pg. 44):

> With the exception of Extranormal and Funds, the attributes you choose for your character usually represent her maximum potential. Most of the time, you’ll improve your character’s attributes by train-ing in one particular aspect (improving skills) or through temporary means (taking drugs or wearing magical equipment). Nonetheless, some  freak  mystical  accident  or  a  supernatural  encounter  might provide you with a reason to improve your character’s base attributes.

You're supposed to be improving skills at advancement, your Attributes are pretty much set for the life of the character, barring, say Cybernetic enhancement, or acquiring super-powers.

### How to Do It

From d6 Fantasy, Improving Characters (pg. 45):

> In the first method, to boost an attribute by one pip costs 10 times the number before the attribute’s “D” in Character Points. Generally, a single attribute may be raised only one pip per adventure, though it’s possible that the effects of the situation influence the character’s physical makeup for a while or the gamemaster may decide that the situation was so life-changing that more than one attribute may be boosted by more than one pip.

There's more rules on pg. 45 on how to do it; the above is only an excerpt. The d6 Core Books (including d6 Fantasy, d6 Space, and d6 Adventure) are [free](https://ogc.rpglibrary.org/index.php?title=OpenD6)

Answer (score 1):

### Star Wars D6: yes

In Star Wars D6, there are simple rules to level up attributes, as well as skill:

--> Attributes can be raised the same way skills can, only the cost is 10 times higher.

IIRC for skills you pay an amount of 'points' equal to the current number of dice of a skill (e.g. `3d+1` to `3d+2` will cost you 3 points).

So **levelling up attributes** cost you `10 * current number of dice` of the attribute.

> E.g. getting *Strength* from `2d+1` to `2d+2` will cost you 20 points